# Как сделать service бессмертным

Tags: android, kotlin

Не получается реализовать бессмертный сервис .
При нажатии на "очистить данные"  сервис удаляется(notification пробадает), как это исправить?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
 override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {

    val iN = Intent(applicationContext, MainActivity::class.java)
    intent!!.flags = (Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
            or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP)
    val pI = PendingIntent.getActivity(
        applicationContext,
        0, iN, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT
    )
    val bI: Notification.Builder = Notification.Builder(
        applicationContext
    )

    bI.setContentIntent(pI)
        .setSmallIcon(com.ilyamart.findphone.R.drawable.ic_baseline_phonelink_ring_24)
        .setLargeIcon(
            BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                applicationContext
                    .resources, com.ilyamart.findphone.R.drawable.ic_baseline_phonelink_ring_24
            )
        )
        .setAutoCancel(true)
        .setContentTitle(applicationContext.resources.getString(com.ilyamart.findphone.R.string.app_name))
        .setContentText("Get location")
    val notification: Notification = bI.build()
    getLocation()
    startForeground(101, notification)
  //  stopForeground(false)
    return START_REDELIVER_INTENT
}
```

Comment: Очистка данных делает заодно и принудительное закрытие приложения. В теории, наверное, на рутованном девайсе можно что-то и на такой случай придумать, а вот на обычном девайсе с обычным, несистемным приложением ничего сделать не получится.

Comment: ЮрийСПб, так приложение я могу в ручную закрыть и  notification останется,т.е ,если приложение выгружено из памяти ,то notification все равно есть , а если нажимаешь на очистку данных , то notification удаляется ). А как же например теллеграм, когда приходит сообщения тоже появляется notification и когда нажимаю на очистку данных , notification телеграмма остаётся

Comment: Я не обратил внимание, что вы не через настройки приложения очистку делаете.Только что проверил - уведомление от телеги исчезает при принудительном закрытии приложения. Однако это уведомление - не ForegroundService. Возможно стоит посмотреть на другие уведомления других приложений в вашей ситуации. Например уведомление скачивания файла браузером - будет ли оно исчезать при очистке памяти.

Comment: ЮрийСПб , А как Вы  делаете принудительное закрытие приложения ? 
Сейчас скачал файл через хром  и нажал на очистку памяти (что показано на 1 скрине ), notification остался  и от телеграмма notification у меня тоже остаётся при нажатии на очистку данных ( что на 1 скрине)

Comment: Я имею в виду принудительное закрытие через настройки девайса -> список приложений -> приложение -> закрыть/остановить

Comment: ЮрийСПб, да всё верно , так всё закрывается , но как реализовать чтобы при нажатии на кнопку "Очиска памяти" notification оставался ( как в теллеге,вк и т.д)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112584/discussion-between--and-).

Comment: В чате мне неудобно( Боюсь, у меня нет идей о возможных причинах такого поведения. Вообще бессмертные сервисы - неодобряемая практика, которой на уровне системы всё должно мешать.

Comment: Спасибо за ответы